# Why Dig returns different results

Tags: dns, dig

If I use online dig tool (https://toolbox.googleapps.com/apps/dig/#A/) for google.com. it returns

```
;ANSWER
google.com. 299 IN A 172.217.164.78
```

i have tried an other online tool (https://www.digwebinterface.com),
it returns:

```
google.com.     299 IN  A   172.217.4.206
```

but on my local computer (Ubuntu linux virtual box).
dig google.com

returns:

```
;; ANSWER SECTION:
google.com.             3600    IN      A       216.58.203.110
```

why on different places , Dig returns different result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google uses different DNS for different areas to speed up the connection and reduce their bandwidth costs (and maybe to point to different servers to do a/b testing or limit results based on geographic requirements)

Their DNS servers are programmed to give different information depending on the connrction and your IP.